File open problems in C
I'm coding a Priority Scheduling Algorithm on C and I have some problems with Opening a File. My laptop is M1 macbook and My Programming environment is vscode. This program is work on Terminal, but it's not work when I execute it as a  Unix executable file. The program said the file is not opened. like this:
File is not opened.
Input
---------------------------------------------------------
Process ID   Arrival Time    Burst Time  Priority
---------------------------------------------------------
zsh: segmentation fault  

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

So I complied it on windows but it still have problems with these codes:
// codes in FileOpen.c
*process = (Process*)malloc(sizeof(Process) * line);
    if (process == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory Allocation failure.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fscanf(file, "%s %d %d %d %d", bin, &(*process)[i].processID, &(*process)[i].arrivalTime, &(*process)[i].burstTime, &(*process)[i].priority) != EOF) {
        i++;
    }

I use the text file for input. this is the text file:
process 1 1 7 2
process 2 0 10 7
process 3 4 6 5
process 4 7 4 2

I want this program to read the file dynamically, so I want to get line which save how many lines in the text file. This exist on FileOpen.c. And I dynamic allocate the process like this:
*process = (Process*)malloc(sizeof(Process) * line);
    if (process == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory Allocation failure.\n");
        return -1;
    }

I don't know what is problem. I would appreciate someone help me. thanks.
Those are my codes that I think necessary.
// Priority.h
#ifndef DATA_H_
#define DATA_H_

// Process Structure
typedef struct {
    int processID;
    int arrivalTime;
    int burstTime;
    int priority;
}Process;

// Result Structure
typedef struct {
    int processID;
    int burstTime;
    int waitingTime;
} ResultElement;


int OpenFile(const char* filename, Process *process[]); // File open
Process Initialize (Process* process, int i); // Intialize Queue
Process* ReadyQueueGenerator (int); // Generate Ready Queue
void ShowResult (ResultElement process); // Show Reulst
void SchedulingAlgorithm (Process process[], int); // Run Scheduling Algorithm
void Sort(Process process[], int); // Sort Process

#endif

// main.c
// Priority Scheduling Algorithm
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Priority.h"

// Sort by Arrival Time
void Sort(Process process[], int numProcess) {
    Process temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < numProcess; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < numProcess; j++) {
            if (process[i].arrivalTime > process[j].arrivalTime) {
                temp = process[i];
                process[i] = process[j];
                process[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    Process *process = NULL;
    int numProcess = OpenFile("scheduling.txt", &process);

    // List of process
    printf("Input\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Process ID\t Arrival Time\t Burst Time\t Priority\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < numProcess; i++) {
        printf("%2d\t\t %2d\t\t %2d\t\t %2d\n", process[i].processID, process[i].arrivalTime, process[i].burstTime, process[i].priority);
    }

    // Sort by Arrival Time
    Sort(process, numProcess);

    // Run Scheduling Algorithm
    SchedulingAlgorithm(process, numProcess);

    free(process);
    return 0;

    
}

// FileOpen.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Priority.h"

// Open file function
int OpenFile(const char* filename, Process **process) {
    FILE *file;
    int line = 0;
    int i = 0;

    // Open file function
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File is not opened.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char bin[20] = {0, };
    while (fgets(bin, sizeof(bin), file) != NULL) {
        line++;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    *process = (Process*)malloc(sizeof(Process) * line);
    if (process == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory Allocation failure.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fscanf(file, "%s %d %d %d %d", bin, &(*process)[i].processID, &(*process)[i].arrivalTime, &(*process)[i].burstTime, &(*process)[i].priority) != EOF) {
        i++;
    }
    
    
    fclose(file);
    return line;
}

I hope to solve these problems
This is the directory structure:
directory structure

I have rolled back your edit. Kindly do not change the question after it has received  answers as it invalidates them.

Process *process = NULL;
int numProcess = OpenFile("scheduling.txt", &process);

OpenFile() returns -1 to indicate failure, you did not check for it.
As OpenFile() failed to open the file, it returned -1 and process remained initialized to a null pointer.
Later operations try to dereference process, instead of exiting on OpenFile() failure, which invokes undefined behavior, which in this case causes a segmentation fault.
This check is necessary:
if (numProcess == -1) {
    // Handle error
    return EXIT_FAILURE; // stdlib.h
}


The ISO C Standard does not require an implementation to set errno to anything meaningful if fopen() fails, but POSIX does:

Upon successful completion, fopen() shall return a pointer to the object controlling  the  stream.  Otherwise,  a null pointer  shall   be returned, and errno shall be set to indicate the error.

And MacOS is POSIX-compliant, so you can look at the value of errno after fopen() fails, and use perror()/strerror() accordingly. Note that man page specifies around 20 different conditions where fopen() can fail, and also specifies that it can fail for any of the errors specified for malloc() and open().

It can't find the file, but I think the location of the file is properly
Could not open data file: No such file or directory
zsh: abort

Then that means that the file doesn't exist. Are you certain that it is in the current directory?

Yes it certainly is. when I print filename in OpenFile(), it prints properly

I am not asking whether OpenFile() received the file name or not. I am asking whether you're certain that the file exists in the current directory.

Yes it is. The file exists in same directory

Are you running the executable from the same directory too?

Yes every files in same directory

Is the case of the file name the same as the string in the code? Are there any accented characters in the file name that aren't in the string in the code? Kindly edit the post and add the directory structure.

Yes everything is right
